# How to add mask image proper?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, image, mask

I want add lights effect on image. I have masked on that and this is my image [image]

For that I have code to use masking image

```
func maskImage(image:UIImage, mask:(UIImage))->UIImage{

        let imageReference = image.cgImage
        let maskReference = mask.cgImage

        let imageMask = CGImage(maskWidth: maskReference!.width,
                                height: maskReference!.height,
                                bitsPerComponent: maskReference!.bitsPerComponent,
                                bitsPerPixel: maskReference!.bitsPerPixel,
                                bytesPerRow: maskReference!.bytesPerRow,
                                provider: maskReference!.dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true)

        let maskedReference = imageReference!.masking(imageMask!)

        let maskedImage = UIImage(cgImage:maskedReference!)

        return maskedImage
    }
```

And result is get to this
[image]
it will get only in white
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to remove the black background and just show the lens flare. For this you can use screen blend mode.

```
func filteredImage(image: UIImage, effect: UIImage) -> UIImage? {

    guard let imageReference = CIImage(image: image),
          let effectReference = CIImage(image: effect) else {
        return nil
    }

    let filteredCIImage = effectReference.applyingFilter(
        "CIScreenBlendMode",
        parameters: [kCIInputBackgroundImageKey: imageReference]
    )

    let filteredImage = UIImage(ciImage: filteredCIImage)

    return filteredImage
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Also it is working this code but it can not get proper size filteredImage. Can you please help me to get original size? @James P